# How are MagicEden's Collection Bids derived?

Tags: nft, magiceden, liquiditypool

I was hoping someone could help me understand how the collection offers on MagicEden are populated.
As an example if we look at the [Collection Offers tab for Degenerate Trash Pandas](https://magiceden.io/marketplace/degenerate_trash_pandas?activeTab=bids),

At the time of writing, the first two bids are `5.9369`, `5.81`.
To get these we can see a request being make to the following URL (I have changed the limit to 2 for this example).

```
https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/v2/mmm/pools?collectionSymbol=degenerate_trash_pandas&limit=2&offset=0&filterOnSide=1&hideExpired=true&direction=1&field=5
```

The results returned can be seen below:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "spotPrice": 6120599998,
      "curveType": "exp",
      "curveDelta": 100,
      "reinvestFulfillBuy": true,
      "reinvestFulfillSell": true,
      "expiry": 0,
      "lpFeeBp": 300,
      "buysideCreatorRoyaltyBp": 0,
      "poolOwner": "HvDf4Cxd2evdYueLhK5LoaiEvDXFXgb1uRrkoYPdvHfH",
      "sellsideAssetAmount": 15,
      "buysidePaymentAmount": 69576705442,
      "buyOrdersAmount": 12,
      "collectionSymbol": "degenerate_trash_pandas",
      "poolType": "two_sided",
      "updatedAt": "2023-01-21T19:35:38.625Z",
      "uuid": "GSVtgv7MioMYonwYPVfsaP9tPfTTCPn2hSmykPh5Udu1",
      "poolKey": "Gj4qebD2dFJUuQGXbtTiST9LjXPVRfkrAPBni2oXtjSL",
      "cosigner": "7RpRDUZBdu5hfmqWvobPazbNeVCagRk5E3Rb8Bm8qRmD"
    },
    {
      "spotPrice": 5810000000,
      "curveType": "exp",
      "curveDelta": 0,
      "reinvestFulfillBuy": false,
      "reinvestFulfillSell": false,
      "expiry": 0,
      "lpFeeBp": 0,
      "buysideCreatorRoyaltyBp": 0,
      "poolOwner": "B94qeRASuZcS7mSg2qb2KpxZ12KVHHXggjHVAdLsWoR7",
      "sellsideAssetAmount": 0,
      "buysidePaymentAmount": 5821620000,
      "buyOrdersAmount": 1,
      "collectionSymbol": "degenerate_trash_pandas",
      "poolType": "buy_sided",
      "updatedAt": "2023-01-21T19:33:07.930Z",
      "uuid": "FE8iXDi19dinqmBbyXw7vxB8muWWXvjXLAkuCe9RMury",
      "poolKey": "4QY3ZbJc9Cuu5FTqwijffaEJ2HpGZuGDspxddkPraS1m",
      "cosigner": "NTYeYJ1wr4bpM5xo6zx5En44SvJFAd35zTxxNoERYqd"
    }
  ]
}
```

For the second bid `5.81` it's fairly obvious to see this value being returned in `results[1]`, but for the first bid it's not immediately obvious how the `5.9369` value is derived.
There seems to be a lot more going on with this one and I can't quite figure our how the different values work together to get `5.9369`.

I appreciate this isn't a typical StackOverflow styled question but I'm at a loss as to where I even start looking in order to understand how these pools work. If anyone could please help me understand this further or could point me to some documentation or resources where I can read up on it, it would be very much appreciated - Thanks for reading to till the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone reached out to me about this question so I figured I'd post the answer here if anyone else comes across this in the future and is interested.

To understand what's going on here we need to understand the `lpFeeBp` value.

**lpFeeBp** stands for **Liquidity Provider Fee Basis Points**. It represents the fee that liquidity providers (LPs) charge on each transaction in the pool. Basis points (BPs) are a common unit of measurement for interest rates and financial percentages, where 1 basis point is equal to 0.01%.

In the context of Magic Eden, the `lpFeeBp` value indicates the fees collected from trades involving the pool, which are then distributed to the liquidity providers as an incentive for supplying liquidity to the pool.

For example, if the **lpFeeBp** value is **300**, it means that the LPs charge a fee of **3%** (**300** basis points) on each transaction in the pool. This fee is used to reward the LPs for their contribution to the pool's liquidity.

Next we need to understand the `spotPrice`. For the second result this has a value of **6120599998** which is the NFT's price in **lamports** (There are 1,000,000,000 lamports in 1 SOL).

So, the spot price in SOL is **6,120,599,998** / **1,000,000,000** = **6.1206** SOL.

Based on this information, to derive the final price `5.9369` from the spot price `6.1206`, you need to subtract the liquidity provider fee in SOL from the spot price.

Here's how you calculate the final price:

1. Convert `lpFeeBp` to a percentage: `300` basis points = `3%`
2. Calculate the liquidity provider fee in SOL: `6.1206 * 0.03 = 0.1836`
3. Subtract the liquidity provider fee from the spot price: `6.1206 - 0.1836 = 5.9369`

So, the final price of `5.9369` is derived by considering the spot price and deducting the liquidity provider fee.